# How to Convert a `Shell Line` to `Text` in Haskell Turtle Library?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

Consider `(inshell "echo A line of text." empty)` has type `Shell Line`.

**Question:** How can one convert a value of this type to `Text`?

Answer (score 5):

`strict` function to the rescue:

`strict :: MonadIO io => Shell Line -> io Text`

so, you can

`strict $ inshell "echo a line of text." empty`

and get the output of the shell command in the IO Text monad.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  See [the definition of `Shell`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.3.3/docs/Turtle-Shell.html#t:Shell)*.

```
newtype Shell a = Shell { _foldIO :: forall r . FoldM IO a r -> IO r }
```

You can only get `IO` thingies out of it. However you can probably get an `IO Text`, and since you're doing shell stuff I suspect you have an `IO` monad context hanging around.

[`FoldM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.2.5/docs/src/Control-Foldl.html#FoldM) is defined as*

```
data FoldM m a b =
   -- FoldM step initial extract
   forall x . FoldM (x -> a -> m x) (m x) (x -> m b)
```

So if we can construct a `FoldM IO Line Text` then we can get what we need, I suspect.  Here's a guess (not typechecked, and this is getting kind of complicated so I'm probably making mistakes).

```
shellToText :: Shell Text -> IO Text
shellToText shell = foldIO shell foldm
    where
    foldm :: FoldM IO Line Text
    foldm = FoldM (\accum line -> return (accum <> lineToText line)) -- Text -> Line -> IO Text
                  (return Text.empty)                                -- IO Text
                  return                                             -- Text -> IO Text
```

This can probably be considerably simplified by using the [combinators in `Control.Foldl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.2.5/docs/Control-Foldl.html#v:mconcat), but I'll leave that as an exercise.

(*) In case you're not familiar, the first `forall` indicates a [rank-2 type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types) and the second one indicates an [existential type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type).